# Installing Java 32bit rpm on 64bit CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, java, 32-bit

Downloaded the - jre-8u45-linux-i586.rpm

Opened console - su

- `mkdir /usr/bin/java`        [No java was installed before]
- `cd /usr/bin/java`
- `rpm -ivh jre-8u45-linux-i586.rpm`    [Tried installing]
  `error: open of jre-8u45-linux-i586.rpm failed:no such file or directory`

Clearly I have it on the desktop

Opened File System - `/usr/bin/java`, which I created

Tried moving the `jre-8u45-linux-i586.rpm` file from desktop to `/usr/bin/java`, but I get:

```
Error moving file: Permission Denied
```

So I have two problems

- Installing the rpm package
- Getting access to my own system

Sorry, I'm really new to Linux, and tried googling the problems, the solutions there are really complicated, I thought I don't have a complicated situation here.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a 32-bit Java?

Comment: I must use it. There is no other way, the program i need to open in VPS is 32bit only. 

If 64bit java is installed, the .jar does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to create /usr/bin/Java or any directory. Secondly, your invocation of rpm is pointing to the rom in the current directory, which is the directory you made, you would need to point to it as ~/Downloads/java....rpm. Finally, you should use yum to install rpms because it will help pull in any needed dependencies. `yum install ~/Downloads/java...rpm`. If you don't do this as root, you should make it like `sudo yum ...`